# Get the Column name Given in POJO for Open CSV

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, opencsv

I have a pojo class looks something like this.

```
 public record Application{
    @CsvBindByName(column= "ID")
    String id;
    @CsvBindByName(column= "NAME")
    String name;
    @CsvBindByName(column= "AGE")
    Integer age;  
}
```

Currently I need to create a Header to generate a CSV where user might only require **ID** and **AGE**

so my header should look like `ID,AGE` and i know the pojo fields. how do I extract the string given to the each field in the annotation.